# Custom "not found" for Cordova app

Tags: cordova

I am loading a remote URL in my Cordova app. Sometimes the phone fails to load the page and the usual browser not found page is shown.

How can I show my own 404 page?

Comment: if you have control on server side then you can set custom 404 page on your web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check using XMLHttpRequest status, if XMLHttpRequest.status returns 404 you can show your custom page then.

```
var httpcall = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "";
..
..
httpcall.open("POST", URL, true);

httpcall.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
   if (httpcall.status == 404) {
       ...
       ... // Your custom code
   }
}

httpc.send(params);
```